# Materialize select element will not show passed options (empty ul)

Tags: materialize

My question is probably really easy. I want to populate a Materialize select element with a few options. I don't want to put my options in the HTML, I want to do it from a JSON with javascript (I get the json from a different service). In my HTML file, I just have an empty select.

In the [documentation](https://materializecss.com/select.html), I see that during the select initalization, you can pass an options object. I assume this can be used to populate the select dropdown. A bit lower it is stated that the correct key is dropdownOptions, and you are supposed to pass an UL to it. I did so, but the UL is empty. Console log shows that the ul is built correctly. What am I missing?

```
  let ul = document.createElement("ul");

  arr.forEach(oddelek => {
    let li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Four"));
    ul.appendChild(li);
  });
  console.log(ul); // looks good

  M.FormSelect.init(selects, {
    "dropdownOptions": ul
  });
```

What could be the reason that only an empty ul appears?

Because the above code didn't work, I decided to just add the  elements to the HTML with javascript, and then run the init with an empty options object. But it doesn't work, the dropdown is still empty.

The init with empty options object works perfectly if the  items are added manually in the html, but does not work if they are added through javascript. I have no idea why, I call the init after I add the elements. Inspecting the resulting html without the init looks just like in the documentation. Any advice?

Comment: Can you not just loop through the json array and create an li for each? Slightly confusing but options and properties are different things - options are generally for initialising, properties allow you to get data from the instance. So you wouldn't pass a UL - that is to get the UL. So when you build the Select, you could append the li's, and then run the init, and then Materialize would turn them into ul>li for the dropdown.

Comment: Ok, like you said, I used javascript to add <option> elements to the select, so it looks just like in the documentation when I inspect it. Then, I added the       `M.FormSelect.init(selects, {});` line, but my dropdown is still empty. 

However, if I add the <option> elements to the html file manually, then it works. What could possibly be the reason that adding options through js, then running the init doesn't work? But adding it manually works?

Comment: I still don't know the answer to my original question, but the second approach now works - build the DOM with javascript, then run init. It did not work for me at first because I did not completely grasp the async nature of my code (I build the DOM after a fetch).